# PowerMockito: can not mock Calendar.getInstance

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

How looks my code

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Calendar.class})
public class TestSomething {

  @Test
  public void mockCalendar() {
     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     PowerMockito.mockStatic(Calendar.class);
     //a few attempts here
     PowerMockito.when(Calendar.getInstance()).thenReturn(calendar);
     // or
     BDDMockito.when(Calendar.getInstance()).thenReturn(calendar);
     //or 
     Mockito.when(Calendar.getInstance()).thenReturn(calendar);
     //or
     BDDMockito.given(Calendar.getInstance()).willReturn(calendar);
}
}
```

But in every case, Calendar call real method .getInstance().
In previous cases, everything worked fine with BDDMockito, but now i have a problem

Comment: Try using `PowerMockito#when`.

Comment: @akortex91 i have tryied ```PowerMockito.when(Calendar.getInstance())
                .thenThrow(RuntimeException.class);``` but it doesn't work

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you share your full code?

Comment: I am trying to achive mocking Calendar.getInstance();
Because i want to use the same Calendar - in the test and in the code, which run test

Comment: Seems to be working fine when I try it (assuming that on the `@PrepareForTest` you use the class that uses the `Calendar` class). As I said before, sharing your test code could be beneficial in helping you troubleshoot this.

Comment: @akortex91 code was added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your actual is the one posted in the original question, I think you are using `PowerMock` wrong.

Suppose that I have the following class which has a method like the one, hard coupling to `Calendar` which I need to mock its creation (via the `Calendar#getInstance` method).

```
public class SomeClass {

    public Calendar createInstance() {
        return Calendar.getInstance();
    }

}
```

For this to work properly and be able to mock the instance creation via the static instance creator, your tests should look like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( { SomeClass.class } )
public class SomeClassTest {

    private static final int YEAR  = 2020;
    private static final int MONTH = Calendar.JANUARY;
    private static final int DAY   = 1;

    private SomeClass someClass;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
        instance.set(YEAR, MONTH, DAY);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Calendar.class);
        PowerMockito.when(Calendar.getInstance()).thenReturn(instance);
        someClass = new SomeClass();
    }

    @Test
    public void testDoSomething() {
        Calendar mocked = someClass.createInstance();
        assertNotNull(mocked);
        assertEquals(YEAR, mocked.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        assertEquals(MONTH, mocked.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        assertEquals(1, mocked.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH));
    }

}
```

Key points here are the following:

1. `@PrepareForTest( { SomeClass.class } )` contains the class that is under test (in our case `SomeClass`).
2. `Calendar` is statically mocked using `PowerMock` and a new real instance is returned (the one created in the `setUp` method).

You can go ahead and use this example which works correctly as a template to adjust your tests.

Comment: Well, the problem was with @Prepare test.
I should indicate there Class which call Calendar, not a calendar.